# vb.net close winforms application from title bar X button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, titlebar

Using VB.Net on a winforms application I have two forms
Both forms are set to "When Last Form Closes"
Both forms have "Key Preview" set to TRUE
frmOne the start up form has a "Form Border Style" set to FixedToolWindow
Here are the sequence of events preformed with the two forms
Load frmOne and click the X button on the title bar form closes and the start button shows up in the IDE
This is the desired behavior
Second sequence of events load app frmOne has a button to navigate to frmTwo and frmTwo has a button to navigate back to frmOne When we arrive back at frmOne we click the X button on the title bar and frmOne close but the app is still running NO Start button in the IDE

**The Question is how to close the application after navigating to other forms?**

The Code Below are the various ways I have tried to solve this issue
I am including the KeyPress Code which does not exhibit the desired results

```
    Private Sub frmOne_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    'frmOne Property KeyPreview needs to be set to True
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 27 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You Pressed " & e.KeyChar)
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
'Public Sub frmOne_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
'Prevent user from closing with the Close box in the title bar.
'If CloseMode = 1 Then Me.Close()
'If CloseMode = 1 Then Application.Exit()
'End Sub

'Private Sub frmOne_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) 'Handles Me.FormClosing
'Application.Exit()
'Me.Close()
'End Sub

Private Sub frmOne_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    'Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Code to frmTwo

```
   Private Sub btnToFormTwo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnToFormTwo.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    i = txtBoxOne.Text.Length
    If i = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Enter Data")
        txtBoxOne.Select()
        Return
    End If
    Dim OBJ As New frmTwo
    OBJ.SPass = txtBoxOne.Text
    OBJ.Show()
    lblFormOne.Text = " "
    txtBoxOne.Clear()
    Me.Hide()

    'Me.Close()'R Click project PassVar Set Start Up Form
    'Best Solution is to have Splash Form as Start Up Form
End Sub
```

Code Back to frmOne

```
    Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    frmOne.txtBoxOne.Text = "Back from 2"

    Me.Hide()
    frmOne.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: `When last Form Closes` is a project setting. You can change it in `When startup Form closes`. Not sure what the *Start button in the IDE* is. Do you mean the ► (start) button? Meaning, you *can see it* because the app is terminated?

Comment: @Jimi YES ► (start) button I fixed the KeyPress by removing the Me.Close and adding Application.Exit() That was a beginners mistake duh But the X button is still not working I will test changing back to When Startup form closes and get back to you Thanks

Comment: @Jimi  The change fixed the issue I had a Me.Close in the navigate to frmTwo code another beginners mistake The new issue now is my variables in the Module are not being used when I only use Me.Hide but that is another question More Work

Comment: Show the code where you are showing Form2 and the code where your are returning from Form2 to Form1. I want to know if you are using default instances or creating your own instances. This is getting way overcomplicated.

Comment: @Mary I added the code you requested and appreciate your request I think the real issue is the fact that I changed  the startup frmOne to When Last Form Closes this seems to be a NO NO Best solution is to make the startup form a splash screen My original idea was to use a Module and create a global Function that would Application.Exit() which was the desired behavior I was looking for NOT from close

Comment: The reason it didn't close in scenario two is because you HID the second form (making it invisible but still OPEN).  Thus when you closed the first form the app remained running because second form was still open (it was simply invisible) and hadn't been closed.  So "When last form closes" was working as expected because you still had an invisible form open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close Forms to get the application to end. I use "When last form closes" in a project with maybe a dozen forms and it works fine.

```
Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    frmOne.txtBoxOne.Text = "Back from 2"

    'Me.Hide() 'frmTwo is still running, To close a form use .Close()
    Close()
    frmOne.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Coming from JavaFX I felt it made no sense to not be able to close the app with the title bar X button why else would it be there Thanks all your answers on SO about VB.Net and SQLite are great Now I can try to figure out which NuGet SQLite to download and how to include it in a self contained EXE

Answer (score 1):

You had your vb project set to quit "when last form closes" - opening a second form from your startup form meant that when you closed the startup form, there was still another form open so the app did not quit. Changing the setting to "when startup form closes" made the app behave as you expected

Comment: YEP I made the change to when last for closes to solve another issue which was my Module had variables to try and document how many times frmOne Loaded so it need to be closed hence Me.Close which closed the app upon navigating to frmTwo I need to have a startup form that is a splash screen and test using Module variable thanks for the answer